# google cloud build - functions@: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "10"

Tags: node.js, yaml, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-repository

I'm setting up cloud build trigger, how to set node version properly? this is what I get:

> Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn
>       yarn install v1.9.4
>       info No lockfile found.
>       warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated 
>       by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order 
>       to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To 
>       clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
>       **[1/5] Validating package.json...
>       error functions@: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. 
>       Expected version "10".**
>       error Found incompatible module
>       info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about 
>       this command.

package.json:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "10"
}
```

.yaml is:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn'
  args: ['install']
  dir: 'functions/autodeploy'

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['test']
  dir: 'functions/autodeploy'

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['functions', 'deploy', 'someName', '--trigger-topic', 
         'some.topic.name', '--runtime', 'nodejs10']
  dir: 'functions/autodeploy'
```

Comment: What happens if you do as the warning suggests and remove the package-lock.json?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I already removed package-lock.json and its doing the same thing.

Comment: I tried reproducing your scenario and got rid off this error by using the `yarn` parameter `--ignore-engines` in your `app.yaml`. Also (I do not think this really matters, but anyway) substitute in your `package.json` the node version `10` with `>=10`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I've tried with parameter ignore engines its works but I've dependencies on nodejs so I need it. Plus I also tried >=10 and same error appears -------->>>>
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn
yarn install v1.9.4
info No lockfile found.
[1/5] Validating package.json...
error functions@: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=10".
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

Comment: Adding the flag `--ignore-engines` does not mean that your nodejs dependencies will be ignored, it will just [ignore engine checks](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-ignore-engines).

Comment: @PabloAlmécijaRodríguez yes it worked with this: (- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn:node-10.10.0') but now I see this --------> Error: @grpc/grpc-js only works on Node ^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0

Comment: Are you currently using `>=10` for the version, or went back to just `10`? If you are trying the first option, did you try using one of the exact specific versions that the error shows?

Comment: @PabloAlmécijaRodríguez I've tried both (>=10.10.0) and also (^10.10.0) but its same error again.

Comment: I got it fixed using node 10.10.0 on npm in my yaml steps like (- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-10.10.0') I hope it will help someone solving else's problem ;)

Comment: I have then posted a summary of the solution as an answer to give more visibility to the community. If it summarizes well the step followed to finding the solution, accept it so other users can benefit from it, if not, please post the exact steps that made it work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Solution achieved discussing within comments, summarizing how the issue was fixed:

- Using the `yarn` parameter --ignore-engines in the `app.yaml`
- Specifying node version on the build yaml file steps, so it would look like this:

  ```
  steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn:node-10.10.0'
    args: ['install', '--ignore-engines']
    dir: 'functions/autodeploy'

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm:node-10.10.0'
    args: ['test']
    dir: 'functions/autodeploy'

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['functions', 'deploy', 'someName', '--trigger-topic', 
    'some.topic.name', '--runtime', 'nodejs10']
    dir: 'functions/autodeploy'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and removing the file yarn.lock resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

For me it solved by deleting the yarn.lock file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).